# How exactly is equivariance achieved in capsule neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, capsule-neural-network

I have read quite a lot about capsule networks, but I cannot understand how the squashed vector would also rotate in response to rotation or translation of the image. A simple example would be helpful. I understand how routing by agreement works.